# Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll' on Visual Studio 2017 (VS 2017)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm getting the error:

> Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll'

when installing a Visual Studio Extension (vsix) for VS 2017.

This extension was developed in VS2015, so i thought i'd upgrade, recompile, and reinstall it, but I get the same error.

This is a new laptop with Windows 10 and VS 2017.

Any ideas to fix?

Here's the complete install log:

> 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version: 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - 15.0.26403.7 built
>   by: D15SVC 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - Command line parameters: 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\xxxxxxx\bin\Release\xxxxxx.vsix
>   5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - -------------------------------------------
>   5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM -
>   ------------------------------------------- 5/9/2017 10:23:21 AM - Failed to initialize settings for Isolated Shell C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe:
>   Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll'.
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM - Initializing Install... 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>   Extension Details... 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -   Identifier         :
>   XXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Company.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7acae2
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -    Name               : YYYYYYYYYY YYYYYYYY YYYY
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -    Author             : OOOOOOOOOO 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM -     Version            : 5.0 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>     Description        : Empty VSIX Project. 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>     Locale             : en-US 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -   MoreInfoURL
>   :  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -     InstalledByMSI     : False 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,) 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM -  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -     SignatureState     : Unsigned
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -    Supported Products :  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -             Version :
>   [14.0] 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -     References
>   :  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>         ------------------------------------------------------- 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.14.0
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -        Name         : Visual Studio MPF 14.0
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -        Version      : [14.0] 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>         MoreInfoURL  :  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -      Nested       : No 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM -  5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM - Signature Details... 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM -     Extension is not signed. 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM - 
>   5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM - Searching for applicable products... 5/9/2017
>   10:23:22 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
>   Shell (Integrated) 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM - Found installed product -
>   Global Location 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM - Found installed product -
>   Visual Studio Professional 2017 5/9/2017 10:23:22 AM -
>   VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean
>   isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas to fix?

If you want to run your extension on visual studio 2017, please upgrade your from extension manifest version 2 (VSIX v2) to the new version 3 VSIX manifest format (VSIX v3). for more information, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

If you want to build a VSIX v3 with Visual Studio 2015, You will also need to add the VsixType element specifying v3 to your project file:

```
<VsixType>v3</VsixType>
```

For more information, please refer to:

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/faq-2017.md#can-i-build-a-vsix-v3-with-visual-studio-2015

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/743061f9-98ea-4c22-881a-b144b0412cb8/can-i-build-a-vsix-v3-with-visual-studio-2015?forum=vsx