# vsix codesnippets extensions under vs2017 - PkgdefMgmt.dll issue

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-snippets, vsix

I have completed the following two guides:

[msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-distribute-code-snippets)

[codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838842/WebControls/)

Even if I download, build and install the solution provided by the Codeproject article author I get the same problem.

The problem is that I can start in debug mode in an experimental instance of vs2017 and everything works perfectly fine, but as soon as I built in release mode and close VS2017 and install the vsix extension it installs successfully, but the log indicates that something went wrong. (btw which is pretty annoying because it's now installed and I have to uninstall it again because it's flawed)

This is the log:

> 20/07/2017 13:10:55 - Microsoft VSIX Installer 20/07/2017 13:10:55 -
>   ------------------------------------------- 20/07/2017 13:10:55 - vsixinstaller.exe version: 20/07/2017 13:10:55 - 15.0.26430.16 built
>   by: D15SVC 20/07/2017 13:10:55 -
>   ------------------------------------------- 20/07/2017 13:10:55 - Command line parameters: 20/07/2017 13:10:55 - E:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,F:\data-cloud\programming\visualstudio\samples
>   not working\TestSnippet\TestSnippet\bin\Release\TestSnippet.vsix
>   20/07/2017 13:10:55 - -------------------------------------------
>   20/07/2017 13:10:55 - Microsoft VSIX Installer 20/07/2017 13:10:55 -
>   **> ------------------------------------------- 20/07/2017 13:10:55 - Failed to initialize settings for Isolated Shell C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe:
>   Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'PkgdefMgmt.dll'.**
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 - Initializing Install... 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>   Extension Details... 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -    Identifier         :
>   TestSnippet.Gernot Pokorny.32bf7e3b-9c59-457b-bf7d-bce58268a165
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -     Name               : TestSnippet 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 -    Author             : Gernot Pokorny 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>     Version            : 3.0 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -  Description        :
>   Empty VSIX Project. 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -     Locale             : en-US
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -     MoreInfoURL        :  20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>     InstalledByMSI     : False 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,) 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - 
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -     SignatureState     : Unsigned 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 -    Supported Products :  20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -          Version :
>   [15.0,16.0) 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -  20/07/2017 13:10:56 -  References
>   :  20/07/2017 13:10:56 -  Prerequisites      :  20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>         ------------------------------------------------------- 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 -        Identifier   :
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>         Name         : Visual Studio core editor 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>         Version      : [15.0,16.0) 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -  20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 -        -------------------------------------------------------
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -         Identifier   : Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.SDK
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -         Name         : .NET Framework 4.7 SDK
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -         Version      : [15.0.26208.0,16.0) 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 -  20/07/2017 13:10:56 -
>         ------------------------------------------------------- 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 -        Identifier   : Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.TargetingPack
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -         Name         : .NET Framework 4.7 targeting
>   pack 20/07/2017 13:10:56 -        Version      : [15.0.26419.1,16.0)
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -  20/07/2017 13:10:56 - Signature Details...
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 -     Extension is not signed. 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - 
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 - Searching for applicable products... 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 - Found installed product - Global Location 20/07/2017
>   13:10:56 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: Looking for master PkgDef
>   file, Path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef
>
> 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: Creating
>   PkgDefCacheNonVolatile 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information:
>   Double-checking master pkgdef file 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF
>   Information: PkgDefManagement initialized 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF
>   Information: RootFolder, Path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\
>
> 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: ShellFolder, Path:
>   E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\
>
> 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefSearchPath, Path:
>   E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions;E:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;E:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef
>
> 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: ImageManifestSearchPath,
>   Path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions;E:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Users\pokor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_7e57f2b8\Extensions
>
> 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: ApplicationExtensionsFolder,
>   Path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions
>
> 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: "ZeroImpact" = dword:0,
>   "MergeRegistry" = dword:3 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information:
>   Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
>   20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefCache flags, PKGDEF:
>   7001 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: Could not find
>   ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002 20/07/2017 13:10:56
>   - PKGDEF Information: PkgDef cache is current. 20/07/2017 13:10:56 - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement startup complete 20/07/2017
>   13:10:57 - The extension with ID 'TestSnippet.Gernot
>   Pokorny.32bf7e3b-9c59-457b-bf7d-bce58268a165' is not installed to
>   Visual Studio Community 2017. 20/07/2017 13:11:22 - The following
>   target products have been selected... 20/07/2017 13:11:22 -   Visual
>   Studio Community 2017 20/07/2017 13:11:22 -  20/07/2017 13:11:23 -
>   Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Community 2017...
>   20/07/2017 13:11:30 - Install to Visual Studio Community 2017
>   completed successfully. The extension has been installed to
>   C:\USERS\POKOR\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_7E57F2B8\EXTENSIONS\GBDXUG45.OK4\

When I now start a VS2017 instance and go to "Tools->Extensions and Updates..." it is installed. Even if I go to the "Tools->Code Snippets Manager..." I see the snippets, but I cannot insert them via right-click "Snippet->Insert Snippet..." or the associated snippet shortcut. (The snippet code itself perfectly fine and working)

This article from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017) does not help me at all. There are too many undefined subjects in this article so that it is not helpful.

And to mention it this is no duplicate of [stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872763/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-in-dll-pkgdefmgmt-dll-on-visual-studio) because my issue it related to code snippets extensions.

edit: I even get the same log error when I follow the [official video tutorial of microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXnGtQ1a8ds) for the vsix-extension-under-vs2017-topic. But at here the alert is working in contrary to the "Insert Snippet..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that this is a known bug. Have a look at the [Microsoft Visual Studio Developer Community thrad](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/36884/github-2114-package-error.html) that does adress this topic.

Comment: yep the preview version does fix the issue.